# Clear javascript source cache laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, caching

I create company profile website using laravel 5.8 and vue js for make it reactive, it's not SPA(single page application) maybe we can call it hybrid, everything run well in local, after i modify javasacript locally then run a command yarn watch to compile and run my web again it runs well. let's say i have uploaded my project to shared hosting. then i modify my javascript code then re-upload my app.js code and here's a problem. the browser loads my previous app.js not my new app.js. i have cleared browser cache it's sill load the previous app.js. how to solve this problem?
thanks

Comment: try with append a random query parameter with `app.js`. for example `app.js?ver=12`

Comment: my code {{ mix('js/app.js') }}, i've tried append a random query parameter but it gets an error : Unable to locate Mix file: /js/app.js?ver=234234134234.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put a random number at the end of address like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js?v=12392823"></script>
```

Comment: i use this {{ asset('app.js?v=12392823') }} and it works thanks

Comment: Keep in mind you **must** change that `v` value **every time** the app has a new version.

Comment: use this one insted ```{{ asset('app.js?v='.time()) }} ```

Answer (score 3):

Better option is to add `.version()` to your webpack mix file:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .version();
```

After that, when you call `mix('js/app.js')` in your view, it will add the cache busting get parameters automatically and the parameter will ONLY change if the file has been changed.